# How to implement Spring RowMapper<T> interface for a compound entity

Tags: spring, row, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, mapper

How to use RowMapper for an entity which is compound of 2 other entites likes this :

```
ClassA
   |____String : name
   |____ClassB
   |____List<ClassC>
```

Comment: By writing a custom RowMapper?

Comment: If it is possible else if there is another solution why not